# FB.ui name property being overriden after posted using feed dialog

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code is used to dynamically create a Facebook Share Results button at the end of a quiz form. The code all works correctly with the exception of the `name` setting. First, here's the PHP code:

```
$ret = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{$settings_Facebook["appId"]}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // calling the API ...
  function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: '{$settings_Facebook['redirect_uri']}',
      link: '{$settings_Facebook['link']}',
      picture: '{$settings_Facebook['picture']}',
      name: '{$settings_Facebook['name']}',
      caption: '{$settings_Facebook['caption']}',
      description: '{$settings_Facebook['description']}',
    };

    function callback(response) {
       //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
</script>

<div id="msg" width="100%; height: 50px;"></div>

<div style="float: right; padding: 8px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()">Share results!</a>
</div>
EOT;
```

The above code renders in HTML as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '439873598753987',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // calling the API ...
  function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'https://example.com/quiz/',
      link: 'https://example.com/quiz/',
      picture: 'https://example.com/images/quiz-categories_0000.jpg',
      name: 'I ranked 1 in this online quiz! Take it yourself!',
      caption: 'EXAMPLE.COM',
      description: 'Aliquam in magna.',
    };

    function callback(response) {
       document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
</script>
```

For my purpose, the above code and outputs are exactly correct. The share dialog box pops up with a preview that looks 100% correct with the `name` field appearing as:

```
I ranked 1 in this online quiz! Take it yourself!
```

But the post made to the user's FB page contains the WordPress tagline in the `name` field:

```
My site's custom tagline.
```

I can't be positive that the tagline is being used. I changed it slightly and it didn't effect new Facebook posts, but it might be cached someplace. I can't think of where else this text is configured - just happens to also be the site's tagline. :S

Why is Facebook overriding what I specify in the `name` property of the API call? Even if it's by FB design, how do I overcome this?

Comment: I have the same issue since a couple of days. Apparently Facebook changed something.

Comment: @Karens This is a new Facebook AppId and new website script. Everything is testing good with the exception of name... on my end it hasn't ever worked so I'm not sure if your issue is related to mine. I suspect my issue is that something isn't configured correctly on Facebook for this App, but I just don't see anything that looked related.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is related. The code and the behaviour is exactly the same. With a difference that for me it used to work :)
Did you try to submit a bug request to Facebook?

Comment: @Karens No I haven't ... assuming you have, any response? Instead of banging my head against the wall on this, maybe it's a confirmed bug - although that would seem to be pretty crippling to Facebook. Hard to believe it would be left this way even for the short time it's effected me (about 3 days).

Comment: @Karens Have you determined where the `name` is getting pulled from? I thought it was the WordPress tagline, but I'm not positive about that since I can't seem to change it.

Comment: The name is pulled from the title of the page (from your link). You can check it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bug, confirmed by Facebook last Thursday.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1214328271924404/

Let's hope it will be solved soon.

Comment: Wow! Sure sounds like the same issue to me. Thank you for this information.